# How to convert Dutch amount in English?

Tags: java, number-formatting

I am parsing one XML file in java which is in Dutch format. In that file there are some amounts which are as per dutch locale.
For example: **TaxTotal=1.027,120000**
This amount is in the string.
I want to convert this amount to double in English locale which will look like this:
**TaxTotal=1,027.12**
Now this amount should get converted to double format as:
**TaxTotal=1027.12**

**My problem is how to convert 1.027,120000 to 1,027.12 and then 1027.12.**

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: Why do you want to convert twice?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried to format the number using Locale. But there is no dutch support like Locale.Dutch. That was the blocking issue for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html), setting explicitly the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) you want to use:

```
Number number = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY).parse("1.027,120000");
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(number)); // 1,027.12
System.out.println(number.doubleValue()); // 1027.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    String sInput1 = "1.027,120000";
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfsin = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    dfsin.setDecimalSeparator(',');
    dfsin.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfsin);

    Number n = df.parse(sInput1);
    DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfsout = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    dfsout.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    df1.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfsout);
    System.out.println(df1.format(n));
```